802.1X on wired network device
I am configuring 802.1X on a network printer. I have the CA Certificate installed and a valid device certificate installed on the printer. I am authenticating with PEAP using MS-CHAPv2. It wants a user name and password. What privilege does the user account need to validate with NPS? Is that logon or just authentication? I have tried my user account but it is saying access is denied. For server verification I can use the CA Cert, The CA Cert + ServID (Common Name) or no verification.
I have tried my account which has logon ability and it still says denied. Does anyone know which a way to see where it is failing?

The NPS logs should tell you where the error is. But questions about applications like NPS are off topic here.

Thanks @RonTrunk. Wasn't sure here or Serverfault this question would fall into.

You mentioned the printer has a CA signed cert.  Can you switch to PEAP with EAP-TLS inner method?
MS-CHAPv2 is a username/password based method.
